# OpenCV numpy to cv::Mat conversion

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I inherited an application with opencv, shiboken and pyside and my first task was to update to qt6, pyside6 and opencv 4.5.5. This has gone well so far, I can import the module and make class instances etc. However I have a crash when passing numpy arrays:

I am passing images in the form of numpy arrays through python to opencv and I am using `pyopencv_to` to convert from the array to `cv::Mat`. This worked in a previous version of opencv (4.5.3), but with 4.5.5 it seems to be broken.

When I try to pass an array through `pyopencv_to`, I get the exception `opencv_ARRAY_API was nullptr`. My predecessor solved this by directly calling `PyInit_cv2()`, which was apparently previously included via a header. But I cannot find any header in the git under the tag 4.5.3 that defines this function. Is this a file that is generated? I can see there is a `pycompat.hpp`, but that does not include the function either.

Is there a canonical way to initialize everything so that numpy arrays can be passed properly? Or a tutorial anyone can point me to? My searches have so far not produced any useful hints.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I dont know if this is the correct way of doing it, but it works.

I made a header file that contains

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_cv2();
```

as a forward declaration and then copied over everything in the `modules/python/src2` directory. I assumed this was already happening in the cv2.cpp file, because there is already exactly that line (in [cv2.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/b2e20a82ba27615a2e55325ed973d3e5ee5b6778/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L582)).

But just adding that include works perfectly fine, apparently. Now I can call the init function when my own module is initialized and it seems to properly set all the needed state.